What is Google Drive's URI for uploading files
I am new to Google Drives and Cloud, with respect to automation. My company wants me to upload to their Google Drives location, NOT in Google Cloud Services buckets. I am planning on doing this with Jenkins plugin Google Cloud Storage Plugin. It is asking for the URI (I am assuming that's what it needs) and lists these as examples:

gs://my-bucket-name

gs://my-bucket-name/logs/

gs://my-bucket-name/$JOB_NAME/$BUILD_NUMBER


I have not been able to find any documentation that talks about this subject for Google Drives
Has anyone done this before without using Python code? I saw some examples but I want to be able to do it through the Jenkins interface if possible. I am working contract and they want me to make automation as simplistic as possible.

I think this wouldn't be possible through this plugin as it is for a different service.
Google Cloud Storage is an object-based data store, while Google Drive is a file-based data store. Although they may share infrastructure, they handle access and functionality differently, for Drive the upload URI for media upload requests is listed as a HTTP URL:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files

As you mentioned wanting to do this through a plugin and not delve into code I would suggest looking for a Jenkins plugin that is intended to work with Drive. For example: https://github.com/general-mobile/jenkins-google-drive-uploader
Reference Material:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create#http-request
https://github.com/general-mobile/jenkins-google-drive-uploader


Thank you. I'll check this out with the REST API. My company doesn't want to use a plugin that isn't officially supported by the Jenkins plugin site.
